# How to get item from DataList

Tags: datalist

I have the following in an ascx file:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlTabs" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" EnableViewState="False" CellPadding="0">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlTab" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url")%>' Tag='<%# Eval("Key") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Instead of iterating through it as a datalist, can I print only Title of item 3 ?  I'm not sure how to pick just one item from the dtlTabs and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
Dim dt As Data.DataSet = DirectCast(dtlTabs.DataSource, Data.DataSet) ' Cast the datasource back into a dataset
Dim dr As Data.DataRow = dt.Tables(0).Rows(4) ' Take the fourth row from the first table

Response.Write(dr("Title")) ' Output the text
```